# using LocalAsyncVclCall in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Actually i am using the [AsyncCalls](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25420) library to execute an Query asynchronously in this way.

```
       while AsyncMultiSync([RunQuery], True, 10) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
       begin
            FrmProgress.refresh; //Update the ellapsed time in a popup form
            Application.ProcessMessages; 
       end;
```

and everything works ok.

Now i want to do the same for load the query in a grid.

so i tried this

```
         while LocalAsyncVclCall(@InitGrid, 10) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
         begin
              FrmProgress.refresh;
              Application.ProcessMessages;
         end;
```

but  obviously not compile because the type returned by  LocalAsyncVclCall is `IAsyncCall` and not a Cardinal.

also i tried this, but not works because the initgrid procedure is executed but not asynchronously.

```
             while not LocalAsyncVclCall(@InitGrid, 10).Finished do
             begin
                  FrmProgress.refresh;
                  //Application.ProcessMessages;
             end;
```

How i can use LocalAsyncVclCall or another function to execute an VCL code asynchronously .

i want something like this.

```
             while ExecuteMyVCLProcedure(@InitGrid) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
             begin
                  FrmProgress.refresh;
                  //Application.ProcessMessages;
             end;
```

**UPDATE**
The InitGrid procedure goes here, the TcxGrid does not provide any event to show the progress of the data load. because that i want to execute this procedure  asynchronously.

```
procedure InitGrid;   
begin
  cxGrid1DBTableView1.BeginUpdate;
  try    

       cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.DataSource:=DataSource1;//in this point assign the query previously executed to the grid. 

       cxGrid1DBTableView1.ClearItems;
       cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.CreateAllItems;

       for ColIndex:=0 to cxGrid1DBTableView1.ColumnCount-1 do
       cxGrid1DBTableView1.Columns[ColIndex].Options.Editing:=False;

  finally
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.EndUpdate;
  end;

end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "also i tried this but not works." above the `while not LocalAsyncVclCall(@InitGrid, 10).Finished do` line mean? You need to be specific, because "not works" tells nobody anything that will help. Also, you're not doing anything that needs LocalAsyncVclCall (or any other type of Async* call). What you're doing could just as easily be done inside the InitGrid procedure itself, as you're doing nothing but refreshing the form and calling Application.ProcessMessages (which is a bad thing, but another topic altogether).

Comment: @Ken, I just update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UPDATE The InitGrid procedure goes
>   here, the TcxGrid does not provide any
>   event to show the progress of the data
>   load. because that i want to execute
>   this procedure asynchronously

You can't populate the cxGrid in a different VCL thread because **there is only one** VCL Thread, the MainThread. Calling LocalAsyncVclCall from the MainThread does nothing else than executing the given function in the thread that calls LocalAsyncVclCall. So it wouldn't do anything different than calling the InitGrid() function in the same thread where your ProcessMessages() call is. Hence ProcessMessages() would be called after the data was loaded into the cxGird what is not what you want.
All the *VclCall() functions are intended to be executed from a different thread than the MainThread.

Without changing the cxGrid's code to support a "progress event" you are out of luck with your attempt.

Answer (score -1):

Use PostMessage to send a custom windows message to FrmProgress.

e.g

```
WM_PopulateGrid = WM_USER + 1;

procedure WMPopulateGrid(var msg: TMessage); message WM_PopulateGrid;
begin
  //load records into the grid. 
  //You maybe can use a global variable to pass the records from RunQuery
  ....
end;
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with the question about LocalAsyncVclCall, and therefore not an answer.